# Can plugins have their own routes?

Tags: plugin-development, routes, controller

I'm writing a plugin. I'd like it so that a request to view the page is processed via a Controller rather than goes straight to a template (following an MVC pattern).

So a GET request to the URL of the plugin calls a Controller method, which makes an API call and then displays a template.

Is this possible in CraftCMS? Can plugins have their own routes file? (I'm used to Laravel)

This is what I've tried so far:

```
public function init(): void
{
    parent::init();

    // Register an event for handling custom routes
    Event::on(
        UrlManager::class,
        UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES,
        function(RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
            $event->rules[] = [
                'pattern' => 'my-amazing-plugin-yeah',
                'route' => 'my-amazing-plugin-yeah/my-controller/my-action',
                'verb' => ['GET'], // Specify GET as the allowed HTTP method
            ];
        }
    );
}
```

I would expect this to break once `admin/my-amazing-plugin-yeah` was called in the browser, but it's displaying index.php correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea with the RegisterUrlRulesEvent, you just need to specify in the array the url as the key and the path to your controller as the value.

```
Event::on(UrlManager::class, UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES, function(RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
            $event->rules += [
                'my-amazing-plugin-yeah-url' => 'my-amazing-plugin-yeah/my-controller/my-action',
            ];
        });
```